Unwrap dataframe while keeping columns from the original dataframe in R
I have R dataframe which has one column delivery_by_region which is a JSON string which when parsed returns a multiple row dataframe. I want to create a new dataframe which has all the rows from parsed dataframe of each row and also keep some of the orignal columns like spend and impressions. Here's my code:
demodf <- mergedf |>
  mutate(delivery_by_region = sapply(delivery_by_region, remove_non_us)) |>
  mutate(delivery_by_region = gsub("'", '"', delivery_by_region))  |>
  rowwise() |>
  do(data.frame(fromJSON(.$delivery_by_region, flatten = T), .$id, .$spend, .$impressions))
  

But I'm getting this error:
Error in data.frame(fromJSON(.$delivery_by_region, flatten = T), .$id,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1

How can I fix this?

Can you add some data to your question by pasting of the dput() command into your question? For example: dput(head(mergedf, 20)) for the first 20 rows (if 20 rows is sufficient to duplicate your issue).

@LMc the first twenty rows get processed fine. I think there is one row where the fromJSON function doesn't return anything that's why the error, but I don't know which row and I also can't figure out how to ignore this row.

What are the dimensions of mergedf? (ie how many rows and columns)?

Maybe the CRAN package rjsoncons j_pivot(mergedf$delivery_by_region, as = "tibble") extracts the JSON data column? An example is here
